# PHP navigate to error page

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

In my website, website.com/downloads actually goes to website.com/index.php?page=downloads (with apache rewriting). I have a custom 404 not found error page set. If I do website.com/dkfjf/fdf, It goes to the 404 error, but If I do website.com/something, it goes to index.php?page=something, so then in my index.php, how can I make it just navigate to 404 error, after I determine there is no `something` page? Because right now, I just load the my 404 error page into the main div (like all other pages), but it's inconsistent (e.g., it still displays website.com/soemthing in address bar, and there's other problems), and I just want to make it navigate to 404 error. How can I do that?

EDIT: this worked:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url = /error" />';
```

(mywebsite.com/error rewrites to index.php?page=error, which is my 404 error page).
Is that a bad approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`header` function](http://php.net/header) to send the correct status code:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
```

Then you can send your error document with [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) if it’s a static file or with [`include`](http://php.net/include) if it’s a PHP file.

Comment: @Mk12: You need to make sure that there was no output before you call the `header`. Otherwise the HTTP header can not be modified since it’s send together with the first output. You can use the output control to buffer the output (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: Isn't there some way I can just do navigate_url("/error") ? (website.com/error goes to index.php?page=error, which is what my 404 error page is set to, but I want /error to be displayed in the address bar.

Comment: Is there no way to navigate to a url as if the it was a link clicked?

Comment: @Mk12: You can’t send a 404 status code and do a HTTP redirect at the same time. The best solution is to retrieve the error document with PHP.

Comment: I don't really care about the 404 status code, just displaying the error page.

Comment: @Mk12: Then why are you asking if your approach is bad when you don’t care about?

Comment: .. What does the header thing do? What's bad about not doing it? And couldn't i just do that first then redirect with echoing the meta http-equiv?

Comment: Actually, since the http redirect loads index.php (same file) with page=error, I could just check if page=error and then send the 404 status. Is that good?

Comment: Yep, it works, I tested at http://web-sniffer.net/ and it said 404 Not Found error.. So now I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: @Mk12: It just works because Web-Sniffer is not following the *meta refresh*.

Comment: No, I went directly to website.com/error (where an invalid page redirects), and it gave 404 not found (because I did the header thing in an if statement testing for page = error).

Comment: @Gumbo: +1 and thanks for the code perfection using `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` suggested also in one PHP comment: http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#92305 that could cause many issues using simply `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`