# PHP or htaccess make dynamic url page to go 404 when item is missing in DB

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, shtml, http-status-code-404

**Typical scenario:**

1. DB items are displaied in page `http://...?item_id=467`
2. User one day **deletes**
   the item
3. Google or a user
   attempts to access `http://...?item_id=467`
4. PHP diggs into DB and sees items does not exist anymore, so now PHP must tell
   Google/user that item is not existing via a 404 header and page.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621972/php-navigate-to-error-page/1621975#1621975) I undertstood there is no way to redirect to 404 Apache page via PHP unless sending in code the 404 header + reading and sending down to client all the contents of your default 404 page.

The probelm: I already have an **Apache parsed** custom 404.**shtml** page, so obvioulsy I would like to simply use that page.
But **if i read an shtml page via PHP it won't be parsed by Apache anymore**.

**So what do you suggest me to do?**

**Is there maybe some trick I could use palying with htaccess too?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. Two ideas come to mind:

- Redirect to the 404 page using `header("Location:...")` - this is not standards-compliant behaviour though. I would use that only as a last straw
- Fetch and output the Apache-parsed SHTML file using `file_get_contents("http://mydomain.com/404.shtml");` - also not *really* optimal because a request is made to the web server but, I think, acceptable in most cases.

I doubt there is anything you can do in `.htaccess` because the PHP script runs after any rewrite rules have already been parsed.

Comment: 2nd solution is great! +1 thanks! True that another request is made to the server, but at the end of the day it's a 404 page so it won't frequently happen that final user ends up on these type of missing pages, even if they take a bit more to show I think it's acceptable.

Comment: @Marco yup, I think so too. Also, the request should be dealt with locally so it will be very fast. One afterthought, for optimum security use `file_get_contents()` instead of `include()` so there can't be PHP code in the shtml file, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Pekka, I thought to use `file_get_contents`, I didn't know I could use `include` for this, so thanks also for that hint even if yiu say is lees secure.

Comment: @Marco both methods are fine, but `include()` would execute any PHP code inside the SHTML file which is good to avoid if it's not needed.

Comment: @Pekka: maybe readfile in this case is even better as suggested by Gumbo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621972/php-navigate-to-error-page/1621975#1621975

Comment: @Pekka: it works because I call readfile on the full http url `("http://...")` so the server calls the page that is parsed 1st by Apache and it's the Apache output that is retrieved by my script. It's the same of file_get_contents, but I don't need to output the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using apache mod_php, use `virtual('/404.shtml');` to display the parsed shtml page to your user.

Comment: uh, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Now I did and +1, Let me check this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this exact same thing yesterday.

Does Pekka's file_get_contents/include result in a 404 status header being sent? Perhaps you need to do this before including the custom error page?

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
```

You can test using [this Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/).

Comment: No, `file_get_contents` does not send the 404. You have to do that manually as you show.

Comment: The soluiton is in my question in the part where I say "According to this answer I undertstood..." just follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking exactly for something like you needed, so you have a page:

```
http://example.com/page?item_id=456
```

and if later you want that if item is missing you are redirected to:

```
http://example.com/page_not_found?item_id=456
```

In reality I found it is much more maintainable solution to just use the original page as 404 page.

```
<?php
    $item = findItem( $_GET['item_id']);
    if($item === false){
        //show 404 page sending correct header and then include 404 message
        header( $_ENV['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true );
        // you can still use $_GET['item_id'] to customize error message
        // "maybe you were looking for XXX item"
        include('somepath/missingpage.php');
        return;
    }

    //continue as usual with normal page

?>
```

So if item is no longer in the DB, the 404 page is showed but you can provide custom items in replace or error messages.